# How to modify a recorded voice to playback and sound "funny" in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, voice-recording, audio-processing, pitch-shifting

I am creating one application which requires recording voice and then funny voice will play.

Is there any library to use this work function better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application provided from the SDK site has a working example of how to use the microphone to record the voice.

Now how to play funny voice.

For that there are no built-in iOS APIs that will do independent time-pitch modification.

There is open source code that implements time-pitch stretching in [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), but I don't know whether this code has been ported to iOS. Same with [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/).

There is a [Time-Pitch Stretch](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/) Tutorial on the DSP Dimensions site.

Some more blogs on it

1. http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app
2. http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/tutorials-how-to-change-pitch-instantenously-without-changing-tempo-like-the-talking-tom-app/
3. http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html

Comment: Thanks Dear it is helpful for me to develop an application. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for good pointers, but I'll point out that pitch shifting isn't the only way to make a voice funny.  There's roboticizing, echoing, and all manner of other DSP techniques.  If one wants to experiment and develop a method, then tools like [Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_(software) or [Reaktor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaktor) can be useful.  But they do not have a way to export the machines you build directly for use in iPhone codebases, so you'd have to re-engineer the processing chain you decide on.